# Bind default RabbitMQ exchange to the default exchange

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I need to bind a fanout exchange to the default exchange in Spring Boot RabbitMQ client and I can't do it. When I try the code below, I see no errors, but the exchange is not bound (at least it doesn't show in rabbitmq admin nor are the messages routed to that exchange). My code:

A message with routing key testq put into testex exchange disappears - isn't delivered to testq queue.

```
    @Bean
    FanoutExchange testExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("testex");
    }
    
    @Bean
    Binding testExchangeToDefaultBinding() {
        return new Binding("", DestinationType.EXCHANGE, "testex", null, null);
    }
    
    @Bean
    Queue testQueue() {
        return new Queue("testq");
    }
```

Is it impossible to bind it that way?

Edit: Is there any other way to do something like that?

Answer (score 4):

The default exchange is a direct exchange with no name (empty string) pre-declared by the broker.

The default exchange is implicitly bound to every queue, with a routing key equal to the queue name. It is not possible to explicitly bind to, or unbind from the default exchange.